# Inserting Text to the beginning of a RichTextBox maintaining colors

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I have the following code:

```
txtStatusLog.SelectionStart = 0
txtStatusLog.SelectionLength = 0
txtStatusLog.SelectedText = ("ERROR: " & MyUpdate & "(" & Now & ")" & vbCrLf)
txtStatusLog.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Only problem is that when a different color is selected, it either never appears or changes the entire text box that color. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works if I change the order a bit:

```
txtStatusLog.SelectionStart = 0
txtStatusLog.SelectionLength = 0
txtStatusLog.SelectionColor = Color.Red
txtStatusLog.SelectedText = ("ERROR: " & MyUpdate & "(" & Now & ")" & vbCrLf)
```